# Append Dataframe in Pandas within a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using this function and APScheduler to add rows to a Dataframe everyhour. The problem is every time it runs it overwrites the previous entry so its not really "appending" anything.

```
def SMSx(frame):
    SMS(frame)
    frame = frame.append(SMS.SMSdf)
    frame = frame[frame.a != "test"]
    frame = DataFrame(frame, columns=['Time', 'Hour', 'Date', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'Total', 'Bucket'])
    frame.to_excel('Sprint_Log.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', index=False)
    SMSx.frame = frame
```

If I use the exact same code (below) and run it manually it works just fine. I'm not too sure what is going on here. SMS.SMSdf is a data frame from the SMS function.

```
SMS(frame)
frame = frame.append(SMS.SMSdf)
frame = frame[frame.a != "test"]
frame = DataFrame(frame, columns=['Time', 'Hour', 'Date', 'Day', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'Total', 'Bucket'])
frame.to_excel('Sprint_Log.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', index=False)
SMSx.frame = frame
```

Thank you for the help!

Code that worked:

```
def SMSx(frame_temp, frame_perm):
    SMS(frame_temp)
    try:
        frame_perm = DataFrame.from_csv('Sprint_Log.csv')
    except:
        pass
    frame_perm = frame_perm.append(SMS.SMSdf)
    frame_perm = frame_perm.drop_duplicates()
    frame_perm = frame_perm[frame_perm.Ready != "test"]
    frame_perm = DataFrame(frame_perm, columns=['Time', 'Hour', 'Date', 'Day', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'Total', 'Bucket'])
    frame_perm.to_csv('Sprint_Log.csv')
    SMSx.frame2 = frame_perm
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue I suspect is that you do not `return` the updated `frame` variable. While you assign to the `SMSx` variable in the function scope, as soon as the function exits that is lost. I'm not sure how this is working however, since you do not first define the `SMSx` variable (it's the name of the current function, or is also a global variable?)

```
def SMSx(frame):
    SMS(frame)
    frame = frame.append(SMS.SMSdf)
    frame = frame[frame.a != "test"]
    frame = DataFrame(frame, columns=['Time', 'Hour', 'Date', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'Total', 'Bucket'])
    frame.to_excel('Sprint_Log.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', index=False)
    return frame


while True:
     frame = SMSx(frame)  # The returned frame will be used on the next iteration
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's pretty difficult to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: is there a way to return the frame and run the `frame = SMSx(frame)` line under the SMSx function?

Comment: just to be clear - your code did in fact do exactly what I wanted it to - I just need it all in one function so I can run it through APScheduler

Comment: @ik629 If you run the `SMSx(frame)` function from inside the `SMSx(frame)` function you'll end up with an infinite recursion. Looking at APSScheduler I cannot see a way to catch return values from functions. Since you are only running the job every hour, could you instead use a file to store the result? Look at `DataFrame` methods `.to_csv` and `.from_csv`, along with a temporary file.

Comment: thanks for the help! Now the function will save the dataframe to the .csv file, then recall it everytime it needs to overwrite. Thanks again! The code has been added in the original comment